# When do Hindi and Urdu follow free word order?

Tags: word-order

Urdu is my first language, yet I can't really think of any sentences off the top of my head where Urdu doesn't follow the SOV order.
A sentence like : میں گھر جا رہا ہوں (I am going home) follows the order.
In what situation(s) would Urdu and Hindi use free word order?

Comment: For the benefit of those who can't read Nastaliq, could you transliterate to the Latin alphabet? [Topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization) is a common reason for deviating from the usual SOV order.

Comment: Mainh Ghar Jah Rahah Hoonh. And that makes sense! Thank you for that, very interesting and i'll read a little more into it.

Comment: @prash Deviating from SOV doesn’t necessarily equal free word order, though. I don’t know Hindi/Urdu, but in many languages, topicalisation still plays by fairly fixed word order rules. Languages like (poetic/literary) Classical Latin and Ancient Greek appear to have allowed truly free word order, but very few spoken languages do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I never said or implied that deviating from SOV equals anything of the sort. OP asked for a reason for not following the customary SOV order, and I provided it.

Comment: @prash I realise you didn’t say deviation from SOV equals free word order, but the question does specifically ask about free word order and appears to conflate the two, so it’s easy to read your comment as also conflating them. I thought it worth clarifying that your comment gives an example of deviation, not (necessarily) free word order.

Answer (score 1):

Sub    Obj     Verb
us nae bili ko mara.
He beat the cat.

Obj     Verb Sub
Bili ko mara  us nae.
He beat the cat.